# Filtering multiple objects with lodash filter function in vuex actions

Tags: javascript, lodash, vuex

Trying to filter a collection of entities (typical blog post) by some values, using lodash filter function.
I'm developing with Vue.js (latest version) and I've a vuex module (post.js) with some getters:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('post', ['postBySlug', 'postsWithoutCurrentPost']),
  posts() {
    return this.postsWithoutCurrentPost(this.slug, this.category)
  },
},
```

I call postsWithoutCurrentPost getter with two parameters to filter blog posts (from vuex store) and get all blog posts with this.category minus current blog post (this.slug).

So, the postsWithoutCurrentPost implementation is as follow:

```
export const getters = {
  postsWithoutCurrentPost: state => (slug, category) => 
    _filter(state.posts, post => post.fields.slug !== slug && post.fields.category.fields.name === category.fields.name)
}
```

Inspecting Vue dev tools, I notice that I've an error

**posts:"(error during evaluation)"**

But this is really strange for me.

I left from this implementation:

```
export const getters = {
  postsWithoutCurrentPost: state => (slug, category) => 
    _filter(state.posts, post => post.fields.slug !== slug)
}
```

which works without any error obviously not taking into account filtering by category.

Why adding a condition does the method stop working? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely something is `null` or `undefined`. Try adding some console logging to figure out what. I suggest starting with `console.log(post.fields.category)` and `console.log(category)`

Comment: Filtering logic is correct and implemented correctly, I've had a problem with an entry not published so, It was undefined in Contentful api response. I've resolve this problem. I apologize for the useless post